# nextAll() and prevAll() selects only one element, not all of them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with divs inside with inputs and their labels like this:

```
<b>test</b>
<div class="dhx_cal_ltext dhx_cal_radio" style="direction: rtl;">
<div>
<input id="5" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="5">
<label for="5" class=""> 5</label>
</div>
<div>
<input id="4" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="4">
<label for="4" class=""> 4</label>
</div>
<div>
<input id="3" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="3">
<label for="3" class=""> 3</label>
</div>
<div>
<input id="2" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="2">
<label for="2" class=""> 2</label>
</div>
<div>
<input id="1" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="1">
<label for="1" class=""> 1</label>
</div>
<div>
<input id="0" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="0">
<label for="0" class=""> 0</label>
</div>
</div>
```

When i hover one of labels with mouse, i want to select all next divs and all previous divs (for appliing some css to them). So i use this:

```
$( "input[name='appointment_rating']+label" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("entered");
  var h = $(this).parent().nextAll();
  var j = $(this).parent().prevAll();
    console.log("now will show hover element");
    console.log($(this).parent().html());
    console.log("now will show all nextAll elements");
            console.log(h.html());
            console.log("now will show all prevAll elements");
            console.log(j.html());
            console.log("_");
      
      alert("now will show all next elements");
      h.each(function() {
      alert(h.html());
      });
      alert("now will show all prev elements");
      j.each(function() {
      alert(j.html());
      });
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
   console.log("leaved");
  });
```

So if a select label for input with value "3", i want to see in alerts html of elements 0,1,2 as next and 4,5 as previous. But i see only 2 and 4, so only one element is selected as next and only one as previous. By the way, for some reason they are shoen several times, not one. What is wrong? And here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/c81wbefg/

Comment: probably the way you are selecting elements in jQuery, see if the usage of + is correct or not

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.html` will only return the `innerHTML` of the first element in the collection of matched elements. To output all the elements, you can loop over the jQuery collection with `jQuery.each`.

```js
$("input[name='appointment_rating']+label")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("entered");
    var h = $(this).parent().nextAll();
    var j = $(this).parent().prevAll();
    console.log("now will show all next elements");
    h.each(function() {
      console.log($(this).html())
    });
    console.log("now will show all prev elements");
    j.each(function() {
      console.log($(this).html());
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>test</b>
<div class="dhx_cal_ltext dhx_cal_radio" style="direction: rtl;">
  <div>
    <input id="5" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="5">
    <label for="5" class=""> 5</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="4" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="4">
    <label for="4" class=""> 4</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="3" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="3">
    <label for="3" class=""> 3</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="2" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="2">
    <label for="2" class=""> 2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="1" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="1">
    <label for="1" class=""> 1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="0" type="radio" name="appointment_rating" value="0">
    <label for="0" class=""> 0</label>
  </div>
</div>
```